# cx freeze : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, list, cx-freeze

```
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
# "packages": ["os"] is used as example only
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}


# base="Win32GUI" should be used only for Windows GUI app
base = None
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
include_files = [(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')), (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll'))]
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "Snake",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "A Classic Snake Game with a few Modifications!",
    options = {"build_exe": include_files},
    executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)]
```

That's the setup.py code I'm using cx freeze on. although when I try to run it using python setup.py build the error in the title of this post shows up. tell me if I need to provide more info and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `build_exe` parameter is expected to be a dictionary of parameter/value sets.  You need to check the documentation.

https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_script.html

I suspect you intended:

```
...
    options = {"build_exe": {"include_files": include_files}},
```